# How to break up a CString that does not have any delimiters within it?

Tags: c++

I have a CString that I want to break up into small strings. It is a string consisting of a constant 2 byte header and 2 byte footer, but the rest of the string has no discernible pattern. I need to break them up based on sizes: so the first two bytes become the header, then I need to extract the next 2, then 3 and so on. (these numbers are in no pattern either)

Example:

`CString test = "1010eefabbccde1f1f"`

I need

```
CString header = "1010";
CString test1  = "eefa";
CString test2  = "bbccde";
CString footer = "1f1f";
```

I read about `sscanf` being used for this purpose, but I have only managed to use it split strings into `int`.

Example:

```
CString test = '101022223333331010';
int a,b,c,d;
sscanf(test,"%02d%02d%03d%02d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
```

This works for strings containing only numbers. But when I do the same for strings by changing `%d` to `%s`, exceptions get raised.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If there is no pattern that they are written with I can't see how you would ever know what to read.  There has to be some sort of pattern.

Comment: `"1010"` is 4 bytes, not 2.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know that I have to separate the first 2, then the next 2, then the next 3 and so on. I know that pattern. Although this in itself isn't like a series of ascending numbers or something. I tried `GetAt(int index)` but VC++ did not like that at all.

Comment: @melpomene they are `hex` values. I should have mentioned that, sorry.

Comment: "%4x%4x%6x%4x" i think. use x for hex at least. you can always check the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Comment: Also be sure to use double quotes for strings, single quotes makes a character literal

Comment: Can you use `std::string` instead of `CString`?

Comment: You say: "then I need to extract the next 2, then 3 and so on" is so on taken from counting numbers: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... or is there some other pattern you're looking for? Or do you just want to split into header, 2, #, footer?

Comment: @NathanOliver I could, but does it offer any advantage?

Comment: @JonathanMee No, they aren't part of the counting numbers. Each chunk represents a different kind of data, so the number of characters in each chunk is different. I know how the overall string is subdivided, it's just that this division has no pattern to simplify it. I need to explicitly state how to break up the whole string into chunks.

Comment: @MichaelThomas Well, `std::string` has iterators and a iterator constructor that make this pretty easy if you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that given an input `string test` and `vector<size_t> sizes` of sizes, you wish to break the string apart into those sizes, and then you wish to take those parts, treat them as hex numbers, and return them in `vector<int> result`.

I'm going to presume that you have already tested `test` to ensure the correct number of characters exist. And I'm going to assume that the sizes include the header and footer sizes.

After running something like this:

```
const auto test = "1010eefabbccde1f1f"s;
const vector<size_t> sizes { 4U, 4U, 6U, 4U };
const auto result = accumulate(cbegin(sizes), cend(sizes), vector<int>(), [&, pos = 0U](auto& a, const auto& b) mutable {
    a.push_back(stoi(test.substr(pos, b), nullptr, 16));
    pos += b;
    return a;
});
```

`result` will contain:

> 4112
>   61178
>   12307678
>   7967

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/90zqnP)